# Tutorial Michael Hartl at 9.4 failure when db:populate (admin part)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I didn't do the admin part on my application. I have just completed the chapter 10, but now I want to have an admin user.

I add the test, I try to verify in console doing that :

```
$ rails console --sandbox
>> user = User.first
>> user.admin?
=> false
>> user.toggle!(:admin)
=> true
>> user.admin?
=> true
```

No problem and the tests are green.

Then I updated the sample data populator to make the first user an admin by default, but when I run :

```
$ bundle exec rake db:reset
$ bundle exec rake db:populate
$ bundle exec rake test:prepare
```

I've got an error with db:populate :

```
bundle exec rake db:populate
rake aborted!
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: admin
/home/tprails/RubyOnRails/new_app/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:populate
```

So here is my **sample_data.rake** :

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do

    admin = User.create!(name: "Example User", 
                         email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                         password: "foobar",
                         password_confirmation: "foobar",
                         admin: true)

    99.times do |n|
      name  = Faker::Name.name
      email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
      password  = "password"
      User.create!(name: name,
                   email: email,
                   password: password,
                   password_confirmation: password)
    end
    users = User.all(limit: 6)
    50.times do
      content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
      users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
    end
  end
end
```

My user model **user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name,  :presence => true, 
                    :length   => { maximum: 50 }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, :presence   => true, 
                    :format     => { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                            :uniqueness => { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :length   => { minimum: 6 }

  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  def feed
    Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

end
```

And my migration : **add_admin_to_users.rb**

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

I hope you understand my problem and sorry for my bad english,

Thanks for your help

---

EDIT : I modify to:

```
admin = User.create!(name: "Example User", 
                     email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                     password: "foobar",
                     password_confirmation: "foobar")
admin.toggle!(:admin)
```

Is that the correct solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Rails version are you using?

If Rails 4: you can remove `attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation` since you'll have to use strong parameters in the controller.

If Rails 3: add `:admin` to `attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation`

You get the error because on db population, you're trying to mass assign all values at once:

`admin = User.create!(name: "Example User", 
                            email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                            password: "foobar",
                            password_confirmation: "foobar",
                            admin: true)`

The error wouldn't turn up if you would add each value step by step like this:

```
admin = User.new
admin.name = "Example User"
...
admin.save
```

More infos here: [Quck Look Strong Parameters](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-4-quick-look-strong-parameters/) and [GitHub: Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)

Comment: Thanks you crispychicken